# How to iterate through alpha and numeric numbers

Tags: python, numbers, loops, python-itertools, letters

I would like to know how in Python I can iterate through a set of conditions.

1. string that has 2-6 lower alpha or numeric characters
2. the first character is always a number

So a short progression would be:

```
1a
1b
1c
...
1aa
1ab
1ac
...
2aaa
2aab
2aac

etc.
```

A horrible example that can do the first two is

```
##Loop through 1a-z0-9
start = '1'
l = 97
while l < 123:
    num = start
    num += chr(l)
    print num
    l += 1

l = 48
while l < 58:
    num = start
    num += chr(l)
    print num
    l += 1
```

I found itertools but can't find good examples to go off of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `itertools.product` and `itertools.chain`. First define strings of the numbers and letters:

```
numbers = '0123456789'
alnum = numbers + 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Using `itertools.product`, you can get tuples with the characters for the strings of various length:

```
len2 = itertools.product(numbers, alnum) # length 2
len3 = itertools.product(numbers, alnum, alnum) # length 3
...
```

Chain the iterators for all the lengths together, joining the tuples into strings. I'd do it with a list comprehension:

```
[''.join(p) for p in itertools.chain(len2, len3, len4, len5, len6)]
```

Comment: if letters was `['a','b','c']` you can do the following one liner, lol `[ ''.join(p) for p in chain( *[ product( numbers, *letters * times )for times in xrange(2, 6 + 1 ) ] )`

Comment: but, dont use that one liner rather use the concepts in it namely `*` the unpacking operator

Answer (score 3):

I would go with product function from itertools.

```
import itertools 
digits = '0123456789'
alphanum = 'abcdef...z' + digits # this should contain all the letters and digits

for i in xrange(1, 6):    
    for tok in itertools.product(digits, itertools.product(alphanum, repeat=i)):
        # do whatever you want with this token `tok` here.
```

Comment: hmm.. will `permutations(letters, 5 )` include repeated letters like `aaaaa`, and will it will definitely not contain alphanumerics less than 5 in length like `aa`

Comment: i've missed that variable length. it seems better now :)
i think we are ok with repeated letters here.

Comment: I am not sure about the repeated letters, `list(itertools.permutations( 'ab', 2 ))` returns `[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]` for me, which does not include `aa` nor `bb`

Comment: `permutations` isn't what you need here. Use `product` with a `repeat` optional argument given.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this problem in base 26 (Ignoring the first number, we will put this in a separate case.) So with the letters we want to range from 'a' to 'zzzzz' in the base 26 would be 0 and (26,26,26,26,26) = 26 ^ 0 + 26 + 26^2 + 26^3 + 26^4 + 26^5. So now we have a bijection from numbers to letters, we just want to write a function that takes us from a number to a word

```
 letters = 'abcdef..z'

 def num_to_word( num ):
      res = ''
      while num:
           res += letters[num%26]
           num //= 26
      return res
```

Now to write our function that enumerates this

```
 def generator():
     for num in xrange(10):
         for letter_num in xrange( sum( 26 ** i for i in xrange( 6 ) ) + 1 ):
             tok = str(num) + num_to_word( letter_num )
             yield tok
```

Comment: Don't use `+=` to build up a string, it's slow. Instead build up a list of the substrings and `join` them.

Answer (score -1):

lets do this with a breadth first search type algorithm

```
starting from 
Root:
    have 10 children, i = 0,1,...,9
    so , this root must have an iterator, 'i'
    therefore this outermost loop will iterate 'i' from 0 to 9

i:
    for each 'i', there are 5 children (ix , ixx, ixxx, ixxxx, ixxxxx)
    ( number of chars at the string )
    so each i should have its own iterator 'j' representing number of chars
    the loop inside Root's loop will iterate 'j' from 1 to 5

j:
    'j' will have 'j' number of children ( 1 -> x , 2 -> xx ,..., 5-> xxxxx)
    so each j will have its own iterator 'k' representing each "character"
    so, 'k' will be iterated inside this j loop, from 1 to j
    ( i=2, j=4, k = 3 will focus on 'A' at string  "2xxAx" )

k:
    each 'k' represents a character, so it iterates from 'a' to 'z'
    each k should have a iterator(value) 'c' that iterates from 'a' to 'z' (or 97 to 122)
```

i think this will make sense than what i wanted to show u earlier. :)
if u dont get the idea please tell me.. btw, its an interesting question :)

Comment: I would like to iterate through this, and place it in a list.  I'm trying to go through all combinations of a URL.  So it would be http://site.com/place/1a then http://site.com/place/1ab etc.  So I'm trying to build the last part of the URL.

Comment: so, u want to brute force(a greedy search) through every possible link named "<digit><series of chars>" thing. rite? ok i will edit my answer.